# Error when starting Podman containers in rootless mode

Tags: redhat, podman

I'm having trouble configuring rootless mode for Podman on RHEL 7.9. When I try to start my container with `podman run -d -p 8080:80 docker/getting-started` I get the following error:

`Error: error resolving storage path for container b065bd672e295adc63f06688e43a9a90ebc78e13786f3674ada92389cec294e6: lstat /home/hallur/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/229e5382213ff34fa979a1cfa9cebb475e51abca44f451e1e2578c67b7cd12e8/merged: invalid argument`

These are the steps I've taken from a fresh RHEL 7.9 installation:

1. `sudo yum upgrade`
2. `sudo subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-extras-rpms`
3. `sudo yum -y install podman`
4. `fuse-overlayfs` was version 0.7.2 so I replaced the `/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs` file with one of version 1.6
5. Made sure both `/etc/containers/storage.conf` and `~/.config/containers/storage.conf` have `driver = "overlay"` under `[storage]` and `mount_program = "/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs"` under `[storage.options]`
6. `sudo sysctl user.max_user_namespaces=15000`
7. Added the line `<user>:100000:65536` to both `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid`

I can run other Podman commands fine such but I just can't start containers for some reason... any ideas?

Comment: A wild guess, maybe replace `[storage.options]` with `[storage.options.overlay]`. I got the idea from [a GitHub comment](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/9006#issuecomment-762375436)

Comment: Which Podman version are you using? (Podman is evolving quite rapidly and things change with each version)

Comment: I tried adding a `[storage.options.overlay]` section with `mount_program = "/usr/bin/fuse-overlayfs"` but I still get the same error. I'm using Podman version 1.6.4.

Comment: I can see that there are newer versions available on the Podman website - thanks for the tip. I'm gonna see if I can't upgrade it somehow, hopefully that helps.

Comment: In the official Podman [installation instructions](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation) there is a link to the [Kubic repo for CentOS 7](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/kubic:/libcontainers:/stable/CentOS_7/x86_64/). It currently has Podman 3.0.1. I built a Podman 3.2.2 for CentOS 7 in a [GitHub Action workflow](https://github.com/eriksjolund/build-podman/actions/runs/975701693). It contains a tar archive that could be installed into a home directory. (Note that it is a bit experimental, though)